# How do I generate random positions of hexagon using svg?

Tags: javascript, svg

How do I generate hexagons in random positions on the svg canvas? 
Currently, my code uses 
`.attr("points", "50,25 86,45.83 86,87.5 50,108.3 14,87.53 14,45.83")`
which hardcodes the current position of the hexagon. How can I generate other hexagons in different positions while maintaining the hexagonal shape?

Comment: apply a random scale/translate transform to the shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y would create a symbol with a viewBox attribute:

```
<symbol id="poly" viewBox="14 25 72 83.3">
  <polygon points="50,25 86,45.83 86,87.5 50,108.3 14,87.53 14,45.83" />
</symbol>
```

Since the symbol has a viewBox attribute you can reuse the symbol with `<use>` and you can specify the position of the hexagon (`x` and `y` attributes) and it's size (`width` and `height` attributes)

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 250">
<symbol id="poly" viewBox="14 25 72 83.3">
  <polygon points="50,25 86,45.83 86,87.5 50,108.3 14,87.53 14,45.83" />
</symbol>
  
  <use xlink:href="#poly" x="20" y="20" width="50" height="57.85" />
  
  <use xlink:href="#poly" x="200" y="120" width="100" height="115.7" />
</svg>
```

Of course the x and y can be random. Also the width  or the height can be random. However keep in mind that the other size should be proportional.

This is how I would create the use element with a random `x y` and `width` attributes:

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
//create a new use element
let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
// set the value for 'xlink:href' of the new use element
use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#poly');
//the random width 
let w = Math.random()*50;
// the proportiopnal height
let h = w*83.3 / 75;
//set the position and the size of the use element
use.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', Math.random()*(500 - w));
use.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', Math.random()*(250 - h));
use.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', w);
use.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', h);
//Append the use element
svg.appendChild(use);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 500 250">
<symbol id="poly" viewBox="14 25 72 83.3">
  <polygon tran points="50,25 86,45.83 86,87.5 50,108.3 14,87.53 14,45.83" />
</symbol>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function `drawHex(x,y)` where you pass x and y as starting coordinates.  On that function the you draw your points relative to x and y:

```
..."x+50,y+25 x+86,y+45.83 ... x+14,y+45.83";
```

Finally, create a loop that randomly generates x and y and calls the drawHex function.  I'm recently working on something similar.  You can take a look and my source code at [this P5js experiment](https://zoada.com/lpa/index.html) and then go to `creaPuerta()` function on https://zoada.com/lpa/js/parametrica.js

Answer (score 1):

Based on Robert Longson's comment, you could do it like that:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const poly = document.getElementById('poly');

btn.onclick = () => { 
  const transform = `translate(${getRandomArbitrary(0, 100)} ${getRandomArbitrary(0, 100)}) scale(${getRandomArbitrary(1, 5)} ${getRandomArbitrary(1, 5)})`;
   
  poly.setAttribute('transform', transform);
};

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Random</button>

<svg width=500 height=500>
  <polygon id="poly" points="50,25 86,45.83 86,87.5 50,108.3 14,87.53 14,45.83"></polygon>
</svg>
```